# pybind11 Обратиться к членам структуры boost::geometry::model::point

Tags: python, c++

использую pybind11 для проброса C++ библиотеки в python, тривиальные вещи работают, но как только я пытаюсь сделать биндинги на следующие типы, возникает ошибка и код не собирается корректно.

Нужно пробросить типы Point и Linestring из boost::geometry:

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>

using Point =
boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2,
                              boost::geometry::cs::geographic<boost::geometry::degree>>;
using Linestring = boost::geometry::model::linestring<Point>;
```

Я делаю вот так:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
  py::class_<Point>(m, "Point")
  .def(py::init<double, double>());
  //TODO: add getters and setters for x/y here

  pybind11::bind_vector<Linestring>(m, "Linestring");
...
```

А при использовании, конечно же, падает с ошибкой, потому что как достучаться до x/y я не объявил.

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    assert(test_points_sum())
  File "test.py", line 22, in test_points_sum
    print('x of p1 is', p1.getX())
AttributeError: 'my_module.Point' object has no attribute 'getX'
```

Проблема решалась бы легко, если бы доступ к x/y был тривиальным. А на практике мы можем достать x/y через определенный код:

```cpp
template <typename P>
double getX(P const &p)
{
  namespace bg = boost::geometry;
  return bg::get<0>(p);
}
template <typename P>
double getY(P const &p)
{
  namespace bg = boost::geometry;
  return bg::get<1>(p);
}
```

Но getX/getY - не является членом структуры Point, поэтому конструкция вроде:

```cpp
.def_readwrite("x", &getX)
```

или

```cpp
.def("x", [](Point const& p) { return getX<Point>(p); });
```

Не работает

Кто-нибудь пробрасывал типы, состоящие из tuple'ов в python через pybind11?
Может быть есть какая-то практика через биндинги стандартных типов, но я ничего не нашел.

Comment: думаю в вашем случае будет целесообразно создать свой тип в качестве Point. Так вы сможете контролировать изменение x y как вам угодно, а с помощью type_traits заставите ваш Point работать с функциями из boost::geometry